# Syncing a Modern Contact List with Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, sync

I'm trying to set up a contact list in SharePoint that syncs with our Outlook Global Address List. Within the classic view, this is relatively straightforward within the Command Bar, as per below:

[image]

However, I can't figure out for the life of me how I do this on a site in modern view. Is this simply not possible, or am I being an idiot? Below is what I see on modern view...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need "Connect to Outlook", you will have to use the Classic View for now. The "Connect to Outlook" is missing in new experience (modern view). The new experience is a new feature and it may take some time to improve.

Click “Return to classic SharePoint” in the bottom, left corner of the page to switch to classic experiences.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joanna - good to know I shouldn't be spending time barking up the wrong tree! I hope they bring the features across to the modern view soon.